# Receiving ERROR 000732 from ArcPy that raster does not exist or isn't supported?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-000732, pycharm

I am running this script to perform simple raster algebra on the pycharm interpretor...

```
    import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
from arcpy.sa import *

# Specify the input raster
inRaster = "C:/user/dark7/desktop/lesson1/USGS_NED_one_meter_x47y367_CA_SanDiegoQL2_2014_IMG_2016.img"
cutoffElevation = 200

# Check out the Spatial Analyst extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Make a map algebra expression and save the resulting raster
outRaster = Raster(inRaster) > cutoffElevation
outRaster.save("C:/user/dark7/desktop/lesson1/SD_hiev")

# Check in the Spatial Analyst extension
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

I receive this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dark7/PycharmProjects/untitled/practice script.py", line 16, in <module>
    outRaster = Raster(inRaster) > cutoffElevation
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset C:/user/dark7/desktop/lesson1/USGS_NED_one_meter_x47y367_CA_SanDiegoQL2_2014_IMG_2016.img does not exist or is not supported

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have already checked to make sure that the spatial analyst extension is enabled in my copy of arc and the data I want to use is not opened in any applications when I ran the script. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I looked into other peoples questions and modified a few things but I keep receiving the error.

Comment: What happens if you put in if arcpy.Exists(inRaster): arcpy.AddMessage('Raster exists')? The raster might be broken, can you open the raster in ArcCatalog or ArcMap? I think you need to put that expression into a Con statement: outRaster = arcpy.sa.Con(Raster(inRaster) > cutoffElevation,1,0) which will give you a binary raster which is 1 where inRaster greater than 200 and 0 where inRaster is less than or equal to 200. Are you meaning to save as type GRID in your save statement? Omitting the extension saves as a GRID which works but is a little antiquated.

Comment: I could open the raster in both ArcCatalog and ArcMap first thing I checked! Thanks for the tip with the con statement I'll use that again! But it was a really simple and stupid error. I typed User instead of Users in my path.

Comment: I typed User instead of Users in the pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods in the `os` lib that might help, specifically `os.path.join` and `os.environ.get`. Considering you're using Windows you can get the [environment variable USERPROFILE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) which is set by Windows (and your system administrator) so is fairly reliable:

```
import os
inRaster = os.path.join(os.environ.get('USERPROFILE'),"desktop/lesson1/USGS_NED_one_meter_x47y367_CA_SanDiegoQL2_2014_IMG_2016.img")
```

In this case it would help to get the location of your user profile from the operating system, thus avoiding the misspelling, though it's probably not a good idea to get into the practice of storing GIS data on your desktop.

Using `os.path.join` to concatenate fragments of paths avoids common problems with path manipulation so it's a good practice to get used to using this method while you're learning; there are [other helpful os methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) that will potentially save some pain later on.